# solidity changing 7% fee to 7.2%

Tags: solidity

we used to set fee percent of 7%

```
uint256 percent = 7;
uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(percent).div(100);
```

if we want to change to 7.2, how can we do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic mathematics.

```
uint256 percent = 72;
uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(percent).div(1000);
```